# Error In Database Creation 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi all I am following the [RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to create a sample blog application 
 i have written on command line:

```
 rake db:create
 (in /home/fb_app/rails_apps/blog2)
 Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in   your Gemfile.
 Try running `bundle install`.
```

why i am getting this error .I have also done "bundle install" still this error is coming .

Comment: Do you have the sqlite3 gem? Is in in the gemfile? Is it on your system?

Comment: @DrColossosi am also getting the same error while trying "gem install sqlite3-ruby" .

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from extconf.rb:3


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

Comment: @DrColossos sorry the above error i am getting after typing gem install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: As Rob posted, to build the gem nativly you need the dev build of ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by installing the following packages

`apt-get install ruby1.8-dev libsqlite3-ruby libsqlite3-dev`

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu (or another Debian distro) make sure you have run:

```
apt-get install ruby1.8-dev build-essential
```